# Could i have 2 links from the same page with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So my htaccess lines look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^meniu/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ produse.php?categorie=$1
RewriteRule ^meniu/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ produse.php?categorie=$1&produs=$2
```

- www.mysite.com/meniu/pizza/ works
- www.mysite.com/meniu/pizza/Quatro_Formaggi/ **doesn't** work, it displays 404 not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL has the `underscore` character

`www.mysite.com/meniu/pizza/Quatro_Formaggi/`

so just add the `_` to the `RewriteRule` to match it

```
RewriteRule ^meniu/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ produse.php?categorie=$1
RewriteRule ^meniu/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ produse.php?categorie=$1&produs=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL has a `-` (underscore character); and your rules don't; so you need to add the `_` to the rule.

Also instead of using `[a-zA-Z0-9]` I would suggest using `[a-z0-9]` and the Not Case Sensitive flag (`[NC]`). So My suggested rules would be:

```
RewriteRule ^meniu/([a-z0-9]+)/$ produse.php?categorie=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^meniu/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/$ produse.php?categorie=$1&produs=$2 [NC]
```

Also make sure you have a rule to add trailing slashes above this one or it will be annoying to any users hand entering the address to remember to have the trailing slash.